# How to start plugin Intellij Idea / PyCharm

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm trying to run new installed plugin called Quick Notes in PyCharm which is instance of Intellij Idea. I know how to install plugins, it's already done. The biggiest problem is that I can't figure out how to run this plugin so I can write some notes during coding.

Can you tell me how can I run a plugin? I've already allowed it in plugin manager.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's already started, it seems your problem is, to find the corresponding menus.
Try searching for actions: crtl+shift+A and enter something like "Quick"